# Formatting a date in Russian in Swift

Tags: swift, date

How to translate the value "12-December", only translated into Russian for further comparison of the months?

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMMM"
let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: NSDate() as Date)
print(stringDate)
```

Comment: is your input the equivalent of '12-December' in Russian, and you want to get a Date from it that you can then compare?

Comment: You may set the locale. Do not use `NSDate` you already have `Date` class.

Comment: `DateFormatter` has `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` which is a convenient way to generate an appropriate localized date format. Consider to use that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the date formatter's locale to a Russian locale.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMMM"
let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
print(stringDate)
```

Result:

> 12-декабря

If you want to see all the months in Russian, simply do:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")
print(dateFormatter.monthSymbols)
```

Result:

> ["января", "февраля", "марта", "апреля", "мая", "июня", "июля", "августа", "сентября", "октября", "ноября", "декабря"]

Also note there is no need to use `NSDate`, just use `Date`.

Answer (score 29):

In case that you need month names like "январь" and not "января"
(если нужен именительный падеж = if you neeed a nominative case)

you need to use *LLLL* instead of *MMMM*

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "LLLL"
let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
print(stringDate)
```